# Data Driven Coded UI Testing in Visual Studio

Tags: user-interface, coded-ui-tests, visual-studio-2013

I am curious about an issue in Coded UI Testing. For example I created a button named Button1. I did assertions and everything is fine. Then I changed this button's name to Button2. Now, do I have to write my assertions again or is Coded UI Test can suit in every different name change. Notice that I am not doing any input or parameter changes, I am just changing user interface. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: what @AdrianHHH said, don't ever change the code in UIMap.cs file as it will be overwritten, i'm sure you already knew that though.

**Can I ask why you are changing a button's name**

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change the test code easily to cope with a name change like that. Open the UI Map file in the UI Map editor; ie double-click on the **uimap.uitest** file in solution explorer. In the left hand pane expand the method and select the action that clicks the button. That should open the relevant control in the right hand pane. Alternatively just find the control for the button in the right pane. View the properties of the button and click on the ellipsis of the "(collection)" value of **SearchProperties** or the **FilterProperties**. One of the items shown should be the old name of the button, just rename it there.